# skip all crash and exception inside library module

Tags: java, android, exception

I am Developing an android library module and use it as aar file in another android project how can I shut down or disable this module if some unexcepted crash happens inside it

I want to do this to keep safe App module that uses this library

Comment: You can't totally convinced with the library without totally test the code. Catching the error in your code when using the library won't solve the problem but only make your code more complex for nothing. Hence the reason for Alpha, Beta, and Release stage are exist. You need to totally check your code by testing; unit testing, Integration testing, etc. You need to check for TDD.

Comment: While you can catch everything, it's an incredibly horrible idea. You risk making debugging an absolute hell

Answer (score 0):

You are right Mohamad
You should keep safe App module that uses this library.

So when you call a method in this lib
You can put the code in `try/catch` block in a clean way
Then if there is an exception, handle it and do not make it crash your app.

Example

```
try{

// use code in another lib

}
catch(IOException e){ // catch custom exception for example if its expected
   // handle exception
   // ...
}    
catch(Exception e){ // catch general expection
   // handle exception
   // ...
}
```

Comment: thank you for your guide
I think like you and handled Exceptions as much as possible with try/catch blocks
but this library module has several threads and async task classes because of that its so complex to surround all code with try/catch

Comment: @Mohamad so if this lib are too complex and not provide the minimum acceptable level of documentation, I suggest not to use it, You will suffer in the future